# Content Provider Throwing exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I added a EditText, Button and ListView to my main.xml file. The user will enter full name or some alphabets of name and will click the button. Button Click event will display all the names and phone numbers present in the contact list corresponding to the user query.

This is my code for onClick function:

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, editText.getText().toString());
    Cursor idCursor = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(idCursor);        

    String wherestmt = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + idCursor + " And " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI + "'";        
    Cursor datacursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,wherestmt,null,null);

    int nameIdx = datacursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int phoneIdx = datacursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    datacursor.moveToFirst();

    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    do{

        String name = datacursor.getString(nameIdx);
        String phone = datacursor.getString(phoneIdx);
        list.add(name + " " + phone);           

    }while(datacursor.moveToNext());

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But, I am getting an exception at following line:

```
Cursor datacursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,wherestmt,null,null);
```

The exception tells something like:

```
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)


FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(1287): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@412c63d0": syntax error: ,content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@412c63d0 And mimetype = 'content://com.android.contacts/data/phones')) 04-01 13:48:46.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1287): at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179) 04-01 13:48:46.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1287): at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be your where has error, you forget the `'` before the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`:

```
String wherestmt = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + idCursor + " And " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI + "'";
```

change to :

```
String wherestmt = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + idCursor + " And " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI + "'";
```

Comment: Yes that was a mistake, i corrected it and tried running the application again but got the same exception :(
Please help

Comment: need the full logcat error message, and are you forget add the contacts permission ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/> I added this line in manifest file. I am not able to save the logcat error properly, dnt knw the exact reason.....when its saved on desktop, ita a blank log file. You knw the reasons for this? –

Comment: well don't save it to desktop, you cn directly copy it from eclipse and paste it here.

Comment: try to select the logcat error message and copy, and paste here.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(1287): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@412c63d0": syntax error: ,content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@412c63d0 And mimetype = 'content://com.android.contacts/data/phones'))
04-01 13:48:46.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
04-01 13:48:46.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1287):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)

Comment: well, i try your code, please use my code `String wherestmt = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + idCursor + " And " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " ='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI + "'";` , must add the `'`.

Comment: hey i added your code but still the same exception.....did it worked at your emulator? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

are you checking for `NULL` or Empty at `editText.getText().toString());`. I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: while testing the app on emulator, i am entering some values before clicking the button for fetching the records, hence in this case do i need to put null or empty checking for the EditText field? i don't think its because of this reason

Comment: can you check just to be sure, its always a good idea to double check.

Comment: was that your problem???? my bad, i thought of that and said to myself that's just too obvious....good you got it working.

Comment: hey i tested by adding null check but still the same problem. The problem is still not resolved. Any help?